# Can't use selectors inside prettyphoto inline "popup"

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

This should work and it does not.
I'm so mad about this thing, please someone explain why this is not working.
I can't select anything inside the prettyphoto inline.
I could use something else, but still driving me crazy not knowing.

Thank You.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                social_tools:false,
                overlay_gallery:false,
                show_title:false});
            $('#button').on('click', function() {
                alert('great');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#inline-1" rel="prettyPhoto" >click me</a>
    <div id="inline-1" style="display:none;">
        <p>I can't target anything inside here why??</p>
        <a href="#" id="button">button</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try delegating event: `$(document).on('click','#button', function () {
        alert('great');
    });`  I guess pretty photo plugin remodel HTML after document is ready

Comment: How would I do this then?     if ($( "#button" ).val()=="something") {}

Comment: #button as no value, what are you looking for? `this.innerHTML`???

Comment: Sorry about that mistake. No, not innerhtml, this is just an example, what I'm really trying to do is read from a textfield with val() like on onfocus. The example is not relevant anymore.

Comment: So consider to ask a new question

Comment: No I am being stupid now, "this" will work:  if ($( this ).val()=="something") {}